# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Academia Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Who to address on the cover letter?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/who-to-address-on-the-cover-letter)

  **Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Should you request graduate school recommendation letters only from those that know you as a researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13706/should-you-request-graduate-school-recommendation-letters-only-from-those-that-k)

  **Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cite a developed version of an algorithm (citation chain)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13673/cite-a-developed-version-of-an-algorithm-citation-chain)

  **Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Professor only teaches what is already in textbook. Should I quit going to the lectures?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13363/frustration-with-lectures)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Complaining about an ISI journal's unreasonable behavior](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13590/complaining-about-an-isi-journals-unreasonable-behavior)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What do you wish you knew as a student before you became a researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13355/what-do-you-wish-you-knew-as-a-student-before-you-became-a-researcher)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to better prepare myself for the application to masters degree programs in the U.S.?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13179/how-to-better-prepare-myself-for-the-application-to-masters-degree-programs-in-t)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What are the pros and cons of choosing my own research topic?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13368/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-choosing-my-own-research-topic)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Will the bad grade in a proposed studied subject be a red flag in my application?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/will-the-bad-grade-in-a-proposed-studied-subject-be-a-red-flag-in-my-application)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Which recommender should I go for getting a LOR for graduate school admission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13691/which-recommender-should-i-go-for-getting-a-lor-for-graduate-school-admission)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Comment: So what does it mean? I have very little context for these scores. My interpretation: Since the net scores are positive and equal to the Excellent score minus the Needs Improvement score, and there are very small scores where they exist for Needs Improvement, the users of [Academia Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com) should be very optimistic about the future of the site. Am I correct?