# Upcoming graduation

Tags: discussion

Here's a short update on my [earlier comment](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/814/2700) on Meta regarding the future of the site, including our graduation…

The SE team decided, a few months ago, that Academia Stack Exchange is ready for graduation. This is based on numerical indicators (activity, traffic, number of frequent users, etc.), on the results of our earlier [site evaluation](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/702/lets-get-critical-dec-2013-site-self-evaluation) (and by the way, please participate in the [latest one](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/lets-get-critical-mar-2014-site-self-evaluation), which is still open at the time I write this).

Despite this good news, there is somewhat of a queue at the “site design” stage. Progress there is somewhat slow, but there is progress: new sites have been released recently ([The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) and [Money](http://money.stackexchange.com)), and some sites designs have been drafted (see [Graphics Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/design-for-graphicdesign-se)).

I am told that the design team has begun seriously looking at Academia. While no commitment can be made, **we're looking at a few weeks before seeing their proposal for our new identity**.

Comment: Should we put some suggestions for design, or it is for us to wait?

Comment: Usually we wait for them to propose a design and then we can discuss it (this is what happened on cstheory for example)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I think “graphic design by committee” doesn't work too well :)  thus, we wait for a proposal, on which we can then comment before it is deployed

Comment: Physics initially had a [community-proposed design](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304/) that [didn't go down very well](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/479/). That said, there's nothing stopping people from proposing design ideas, in the understanding that the design team can very well (or is even likely to) not use them in any way.

Comment: Any further updates on this ?

Comment: I thought Academia graduating would be called "The Workplace", which already has a site! *ba dum dum... crash!*